# Separate ON CONFLICT for each inserted row

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, case, sql-insert

I have next query which doesn't works:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (id, data, type_id) 
          VALUES (12, 'text', 4)
          ON CONFLICT(id, type_id) DO UPDATE SET data = 'www',
          (11, 'ooo', 4)
          ON CONFLICT(id, type_id) DO UPDATE SET level = 'kkk'
```

How I can add separate ON CONFLICT for each inserted row?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CASE expression in the SET part:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (id, data, type_id) 
VALUES (12, 'text', 4), (11, 'ooo', 4)
ON CONFLICT(id, type_id) DO UPDATE 
  SET data = case 
               when excluded.id = 12 then 'www'
               when excluded.id = 11 then 'kkk'
             end
```

Comment: There is one issue, actually I am using JS map() function to build such query. So, all data will be copy/paste after each iteration. so it is hard to have unique  ON CONFLICT(id, type_id) DO UPDATE  SET

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a `case` expression. It is a bit cumbersome, because you want to update different columns, but the logic is:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (id, data, type_id) 
VALUES (12, 'text', 4), (11, 'ooo', 4)
ON CONFLICT(id, type_id) DO UPDATE SET 
    data  = CASE WHEN id = 12 THEN 'www' ELSE data END,
    level = CASE WHEN id = 11 THEN 'kkk' ELSE level END
```